# frequently stops and freezes -- Ubuntu 21.10 (GNU/Linux 5.13.0-22-generic x86_64) -- moved to debian 11 now and issue is gone

Tags: dell, freeze, 21.10

I was running Ubuntu MATE LTS for a long time.
Then i moved to Budgie LTS and then current version.

Here it starts that my machine (DELL XPS 850 - 16 GB RAM) stops frequently completely (several times a day).
Then I moved to UBUNTU LTS and then to the current version. Same topic.
Several times a day the machine freezes fully. No response, no key press.
When i restart and look in /var/log i find no traces of the crash.

I' have 16GB RAM, 2GB swap and run Firefox mostly only firefox and evolution. Hibernation is turned off. Librenms is not showing any memory or cpu issues when it comes to a crash.

Problem is fixed now: I moved to Debian 11, no issue since then.

Comment: `htop` to check what is taking al your CPU/Disk/RAM.`journalctl -p warnings` to get log errors with that priority. `sudo ubuntu-drivers install` to (maybe)  use a better drivers.

Comment: Not seeing a question here.

Answer (score 0):

System "freezes" are often caused by running too many, too large programs and running out of available memory. Use `free` to see if you have swap space, read `man mkswap swapon fstab` to create some. Swap space must be contiguous. use `mkswap` or `fallocate`, not `dd`. Traditionally, swap space of 1.5 × RAM has been recommended,  but YMMV. If you don't plan to hibernate your system, you can have less than 1.0 × RAM.

Comment: hi, thanks for the hint. I' have 16GB RAM, 2GB swap and run Firefox mostly only firefox and evolution.  Hibernation is turned off.  Librenms is not showing any memory or cpu  issues when it comes to a crash.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit].

Answer (score -1):

I have upgraded the ubuntu 21 10, and it started to freeze on startup (up to 2 minutes to start up), when before the upgrade it was starting up in 20 seconds.

Currently i have found that the problem is in linux kernel version. Ubuntu 21.10 by default runs on 5.13.0. so when i select 5.11.0 in GRUB menu it works fine.